# How can I add an external folder of java code to my gradle project with a relative path?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle Java project that I want to reference other java code that exists in another repo. I am not quite sure how to do this.

My existing build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    // implementation project(':project1')
    // implementation files('../../project1/lib/build/libs/lib.jar')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'project2.App'
}
```

What can I add to this file, to have it reference a relative path that points to a folder with java source files in it?

Comment: You can use it like a sub-project, or even build a jar and include it in the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle`, or create a library and publish it over maven local. Which way is more fit for you so I can explain a bit more about.

Comment: I want the build to work with all local dependencies. If I change code in one project I want the build of the other project to pick that up.

Comment: hmmm, then would it be sufficient to say, That project2 depends on project1 ? if not, would there be an issue if you made a project3 as a parent for both of project1 and project2 ? I've never had a case where I need to depend on another separate project, unless its just a piece of code only, this way project2 can act like a library for project1.

Comment: Yes. Project2 depends on Project1. I am not sure why this is not an incredibly common use case? I have a folder that contains a repo of java gradle project. I have another folder that contains a gradle java project that has a dependency on the first one. How can I do this?

Comment: I've added an answer, Its an incredibly common case unless I did not get well what you want. let me know if there is some issues.

Comment: You can use [Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) to 'connect' two otherwise unrelated Gradle projects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, According to the discussion in the comments, here is how to do it.

`project1` has its own `build.gradle` and `setting.gradle`

go `setting.gradle` and add the following after cloning the repo inside `project1` folder:

```
include ':project2'
```

Now, In your `project1` in `build.gradle` file You can add `project2` to `dependencies` section so it will look like this :

```
dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    implementation project(':project2')
}
```

the final result :

Any time you build `project1`, `project2` will be built as well.

Any update for `project2` will be effected immediately to `project1` after any build operation.

Might be helpful to read official [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) about multi project builds.

If you don't want to clone `project2` inside `project1`, Then build `project2` with gradle command line `gradle build`

This will result in a Jar file created at `project2/build/libs/project2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Then you can add it to `project1` with a relative path to this Jar like this:

```
implementation files('../project2/build/libs/project2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

Comment: I am not cloning project1 into project2. They exist as sibling directories, not one under the other. There are multiple projects that depend on project1, so I am not cloning it into every project.

Comment: I'll update the answer.